# component joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I have a problem with a component in Joomla I want to call other function when the component start

```
$controller = JController::getInstance('Productos');
$controller->execute(JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('task'));
$controller->redirect();
```

Here I want to call a function to select in the database only one item not all

Y try this

```
$controller->execute(JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('other'));
```

and in my

```
class ProductosController extends JController
{

function Other(){
...
}

}
```

But my code never pass for Other function.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('task')` will either return a controller/function pair or just a function name. If it is a controller/function pair, it will return a string in this format: 'controller.function'. Notice the separation on a period. If returning a function, it will just be the function name.

The modification you have made to the script has caused it to look for a request variable (i.e. post or get variable) with the name "other" instead of the name "task". (Task is the standard Joomla variable to pass the task.)

If you actually wanted to always call that particular function you would change the line to this:

```
$controller->execute('Productos.other');
```

Likewise, you could also just adapt the page that is calling this, so that the url either contains `task=productos.other` or there is a hidden input form field like such:

```
<input type="hidden" name="task" value="productos.other" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The better way of call the controller method is:

```
$controller = JControllerLegacy::getInstance('Other');
$controller->execute(JFactory::getApplication()->input->getCmd('task'));
```

using `getCmd()` call the controller task, and task is not pass in url so you do not get the task using `get()` method.

Try this code and get the solution of your problem.